# Running Solver across a range of columns using VBA in Excel

Tags: excel, vba, solver

So I wrote a macro for Solver to iterate over a bunch of columns each concerning a single SKU. The macro is stuck at 'Setting up problem...' and would not budge.

This is what the Solver is supposed to do:

1)Change cell B2 until the value in Cell B381 is equal to B382.

2) Iterate over to the next column and repeat this for next 29 columns.

Please help me out, I would be most grateful!
Thanks a lot.

```
Sub optimizer()
'
' optimizer Macro
'

'
Dim setCellRange As Range, valueOfRange As Range, byChangeRange As Range

Set setCellRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B381")
Set valueOfRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B382")
Set byChangeRange = ActiveSheet.Range("B2")
Dim i As Long

For i = 1 To 30
    SolverReset
    SolverOk SetCell:=setCellRange.Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=valueOfRange.Address, ByChange:=byChangeRange.Address, Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverOk SetCell:=setCellRange.Address, MaxMinVal:=3, ValueOf:=valueOfRange.Address, ByChange:=byChangeRange.Address, Engine _
        :=1, EngineDesc:="GRG Nonlinear"
    SolverSolve (True)
    Set setCellRange = setCellRange.Cells(1, 2)
    Set valueOfRange = valueOfRange.Cells(1, 2)
    Set byChangeRange = byChangeRange.Cells(1, 2)
Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: So your current code works on column "B" but you want it to work for next 29 columns?

Comment: `GRG Nonlinear` suggests that you are using floating-point calculations. These typically involve round-off error. Perhaps B381is never actually equal to B382 and you are hanging in an infinite loop. Perhaps you can adjust precision and/or timeout in the solver options.

Comment: Was finally able to get the code running for rest of the columns by changing to a lower number of iterations before timeout, so @John's suggestion helped. I thought solver would reach equality, not an estimate.